# How replace the first 3 characters in word?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to replace the first 3 characters in a word entered by the user.
For example if the user entered:

> Картошка

After replacing the first three characters, the result might be:

> Хуитошка

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: If you do not understand basic programming concepts (and how to use the reference materials) well enough to figure this out you should not be programming in Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks instead of telling him how crap he is, perhaps you could advise him on how he could improve his skills?

Comment: @gavdotnet - I did:  Learn basic programming concepts and learn how to use reference materials.  Until he does this he should not be programming in Objective-C, since he will develop some serious misconceptions and bad habits that will be hard to break.

Comment: @user3546142 From your question it seems like you are just starting out programming for iOS. Have you been through any books or tutorials yet? If not, I'd recommend it. [The Ray Wenderlich site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) has some good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the first three characters with any string:

```
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) withString:@"abc"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
```

Pls refer below link for complete information on this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html